# Questions about indexing in SQL with Clustered and Non-clustered

Tags: sql, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

If i have table with two column: `id` and `priority`.

- Id is primary key
- priority is number, unique and have indexing (Non-clustered).

So if i search by id or by priority. Which one is faster and why?

Comment: You could just try it (with both) and measure the time by yourself? That would have answered your question more quickly than it took aksing it here. .

Comment: thanks for your quick response. but i want to know the algorithm behide. can u explain for me?

Comment: Also did you wanted to write `primary` key or not? If not, can you please explain what a `priority` key is? And `Which one is faster` instead of `quick one is faster`

Comment: Both should be pretty fast as they are index seeks on unique indexes. In general the NCI might be faster as they are usually  smaller and may have fewer levels (though not in your two column example) - but only if it contains all columns required by the rest of the query. Otherwise you will get a lookup back to the CI anyway.

Comment: @LeDinhDam the algorithm is the same, except the fields you compare and which values you compare. Please just try it out and see which one is faster for your data in your database

Comment: Your edit has changed the question. Are you saying that username isn't indexed after all?

Comment: Sorry, i update my question again. because the type of id is a number and the type of username is probably some sort of varchar(). so maybe it affect the speed.

Comment: @cramopy: thanks for your reply, i updated the question. and also try to measure it. i see that id to be slightly faster than priority.

Comment: @LeDinhDam so you could have answered the question by yourself (kind of)?

Comment: yep. @Gordon Linoff also answer me about the algorithm.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name, just ask about algorithm

Answer (score 2):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

This has little to do with clustered versus non-clustered indexing.  Presumably, the type of `id` is a number (usually such columns are integers and hence four bytes).  The type of `username` is probably some sort of `varchar()`.

When searching through a B-Tree index -- whether clustered or not -- fixed length keys have a slight advantage.  Hence, I would expect `id` to be slightly faster than `username`.

Does this make a difference in real world applications?  I really doubt it.  In a large-ish table, the time for query processing is typically dominated by I/O time loading the index and/or pages.  Not always.  But micro-optimizations (nano-opimizations?) generally have much less impact than one would expect.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. i got it

Comment: I also change `username` to priority.

Comment: @LeDinhDam . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions, not as edits to questions that invalidate answers.

Comment: sorry about that.